# Eigenvalues of $3\times3$ matrix containing $1$ to $9$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The eigenvalues of any $3\times3$ matrix with entries $1,2,3,\ldots,9$ in arbitrary permutation seem to be real. How would one proof this?

Answer (score 2):

Try (taking a random example)
$$ \pmatrix{8 & 5 & 6\cr 4 & 3 & 9\cr 7 & 2 & 1\cr} $$

In fact, by actual count, $109212$ of the $9!=362880$ permutations have two non-real eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you. I seem to have picked some lucky examples when trying this out.